# Python Canvas bbox returns None

Tags: python, tkinter

so i am making a game (Minecraft 2D (scuffed edition)) and if you are underground in a cave, i want the background to be dark, not that you can see the sun if you are in a cave, so what i do is i want to check for the lowest grass block on screen (witch is ground level)
and then place the cave background atthat location, but when i trie to get the bbox or the coords of a block object on the canvas, it just gives me `None`.

So i have this now:
(the camera function gets run every time the player moves)

```
    def camera(self):
    for i in self.block_sprites:
        self.canvas.delete(i.get_image())
    for i in self.sprites:
        self.canvas.delete(i)
    self.draw_current_pos()
    self.draw_background()

def add_block_sprite(self, x, y, block_type):
    self.current_sprite = Block(x, y, self, block_type)
    self.block_sprites.append(self.current_sprite)

def draw_current_pos(self):
    self.sprites = []
    self.block_sprites = []
    for x in range(0, 20):
        for y in range(0, 21):
            if self.world.world[self.posx+x][self.posy+y] == 0 :
                continue
            else:
                self.add_block_sprite(x, y, self.world.world[self.posx + x][self.posy + y])

def draw_background(self):
    grass_y = 1000
    test_for_grass = False
    for block in self.block_sprites:
        if block.get_type() == 1:
            print(self.canvas.bbox(block))              #prints "None"
            if self.canvas.bbox(block)[1] > grass_y:    ####error here####
                grass_y = self.canvas.coords(block)[1]
                test_for_grass = True
    if not test_for_grass and self.posy < 30:
        grass_y = 1000 - grass_y
    cave = self.canvas.create_image(0, grass_y, image=self.cavebg, anchor="nw")
    self.sprites.append(cave)
```

Do you know what the problem is?
I hope you can help!
(if this it to little code for the problem tell me)

Comment: On that line, you know that `block` is a `Block` object not a `tkinter.Canvas` object id.

Comment: Whoops! that was the problem!

Comment: :D Next time just add a `print(block)`. It should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thats a good idea thanks!

Comment: btw why are You creating a game in tkinter? it is already "slow" to make a game in python (not the best language for game dev) but it probably would be better to use some game library for that for example `pygame` or `ursina engine` (which btw provides simple 3d stuff tho You can make Your own models and stuff)